# How to upload file using REST Web Service?

Tags: wcf, rest

I have a requirement to upload a audio file from java application through c# wcf restfull web service.
 So how to create a rest web service to upload a file.

Comment: Can you specify your question? what is the detailed problem?

Comment: it depends on the logic on the other end if he's using base64 encoding , you can convert to base64 and send it